# accessing chrome extension functions in console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

If I create a bunch of functions in a chrome extension, is there anyway to access them through the console?

for example:

**contentScript.js**

```js
function test() {
    console.log('hello')
}
```

then be able to run `test()` in the console

Comment: Switch the [context](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#context) in devtools console toolbar to your extension.

Comment: thanks! if you can put this as an answer I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The content scripts run in an "isolated world" which is a different context. By default devtools works in the page context so you need to [switch the context selector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/reference#context) in devtools console toolbar to your extension:

[image]

An alternative solution is to expose the functions in the page context by putting them into a `<script>` element in the web page, but that won't be your content script anymore, it'd be just a normal page script function ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879)).

Answer (score -1):

You can access your extension's console by right click on the extension popup and then selecting "Inspect".

Comment: The OP is using a content script, which is a different thing.